# When was the first time Batman disappeared at the end of a conversation?

Tags: dc, comics, history-of, batman

Batman has a habit of talking to someone like Commissioner Gordon, then disappearing when their back is turned.

[image: Batman talks to Commissioner Gordon and disappears]

When was the very first time that Batman did this, either in the comics or some other medium?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### The first time we see Batman pull off his iconic vanishing act was back in 1972.

---

In **Detective Comics: Issue #424 (1972)**, Batman is discussing with Commissioner Gordon about a murder of a stockbroker. At this time, Batman *vanishes* for the first time (*image below*).

[image]
 <sub>*[Detective Comics #424](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Detective_Comics_Vol_1_424) (Page 3-4)*</sub>

This is the first time he does it in any media (*movies, comics, TV series etc.*).

If you want to know *how* he does it, you can find the answer to that [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48958/how-does-batman-disappear)

---

The second time we see it was in 1973 (**Swamp Thing: Issue # 7**) when he's investigating the presence of a monster (Swamp Thing) in Gotham.

[image]
 <sub>*[Swamp Thing #7](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Swamp_Thing_Vol_1_7) (Page 8)*</sub>

Comment: Is the second example also the first time he appears out of the dark to speak to an ally? Also, how can Gordon get the government's "secret files"?

Comment: Nice finds. Congrats on 10k by the way!

Comment: @Taladris most probably yes. Need to check it though

Answer (score 7):

He's been doing it since his very first appearance.

See this page from his first story, in [*Detective Comics #27*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detective_Comics_27) (1939).

[image]

Comment: "A fitting end for his kind."